# How do I get the matching object from a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a matching object from this collection, IEnumerable by checking if the ids of the collection match to a specific id, SelectedProc.Req.SPId. How can I return the matching object?

Currently, it is giving me a bool instead of the matching object.

```
var opObj = (await dataRepo.GetOperators()) //Returns Task<IEnumerable<Operator>>
    .Where(a => string.Equals(a.ProcType, "ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(x => x.ID == SelectedProc.Req.SPId);
```

Comment: Omit the `Select`. The `Where`.clause already filters those elements that match your condition, select would simply return for every element **if** its id matches `SelectedProc.Req.SPId`, which you allready ensured in the where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is selecting a specific value from each element in the collection:

```
.Select(x => x.ID == SelectedProc.Req.SPId)
```

That value is:

```
x.ID == SelectedProc.Req.SPId
```

Which is a boolean.  If you just want the collection itself and not any transformation of it, remove the `.Select()` entirely:

```
var opObj = (await dataRepo.GetOperators()) //Returns Task<IEnumerable<Operator>>
    .Where(a => string.Equals(a.ProcType, "ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Or, if you wanted that previous code to be an additional condition, add it as an additional condition:

```
var opObj = (await dataRepo.GetOperators()) //Returns Task<IEnumerable<Operator>>
    .Where(a => string.Equals(a.ProcType, "ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Where(x => x.ID == SelectedProc.Req.SPId)
```

This would return a collection.  If you want to return only the single matching item, use `.Single()` instead:

```
var opObj = (await dataRepo.GetOperators()) //Returns Task<IEnumerable<Operator>>
    .Where(a => string.Equals(a.ProcType, "ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Single(x => x.ID == SelectedProc.Req.SPId)
```

Other options include `.SingleOrDefault()`, `.First()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`, etc.

Basically, `.Select()` will select *all* elements and apply its argument to *transform* the results.  `.Where()` will *filter* the results.  And things like `.Single()` or `.First()` will execute the expression tree and return an element from the results.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for Single or SingleOrDefault()! :)